# There was a problem while parsing the package” on Android 12

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

While Installing on Android 12 I'm getting this error

```
adb: failed to install C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure     
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl159430148.tmp/base.apk (at 
Binary XML file line #263): com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: Targeting S+      
(version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

AndroidManifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ordeno">
         
   <application
        android:label="abcd"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="**********" />


        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              /> <!-- stripe flutter -->
              
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="sdk"
                    android:host="3ds.sdk.io" />
            </intent-filter>


            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>              
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="dummy.page" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />  
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon"
            />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"
            />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/default_color"
            />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have added `andriod:exported="true"` to all the activity tag's, it still shows the same

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of `flutter_local_notifications` library.
Adding below lines inside `<application></application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` will fix the problem.

```
<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" /> 
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" /> 
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> 
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```